# Add share on facebook button on webpage

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to add fb share in drupal site i want to do it with javascript so I followed following steps

1. Created on app page through Facebook developer
2. There I have created app and got appid and code to put on my template following is the code

```
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=myappid";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>
```

I am getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fb_app_id' of undefined this error in
>   console

Do I need to link any other js file something I am missing because of that share button not coming

Comment: Are you running that on a local file, or a URL which is accessible via http:// or https:// ?